# How do I use NGINX to route to multiple apps?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have been messing around with NGINX (complete novice) and a home lab server. I have a few docker apps that I want to access via my domain. I have set up the https redirect and verified that it works. However my issue is getting the domain [www.mydomain.net/app1](http://www.mydomain.net/app1) to resolve to app1 and [www.mydomain.net/app2](http://www.mydomain.net/app2) to resolve to app2.

Here is my current config

```
server { 
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.net www.mydomain.net;

  *insert ssl configs*

  location /tsd/ {
    proxy_pass http://tsd:3334/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header x-Forwareded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location /game/ {
    proxy_pass http://game:5876/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header x-Forwareded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I looked at the network tab headers after going to mydomain.net/tsd I see the request go in and then get a response header with location /printers/ instead of /tsd/printers/. I have tried a multitude of various things from stackoverflow and other sites to try and make the /tsd/ path stick.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the leading slash on `proxy_pass`, like `proxy_pass http://tsd:3334;`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That unfortunately didnt work. In the mean time I decided to go with www.{desccriptor}.mydomain.com to process requests properly. I had to go through making a wildcard cert, but it is functioning as expected.